# Maximum/Minimum Modulus Principle Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| \geq \sqrt{|z|}$ for all $|z|\leq 1$. I want to show that $|f(0)|\geq 1$.

Now, assume f has no zeros. Then, the minimum of $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ is attained on the boundary when $|z| = 1$. However, this means that any minimum $z_0$ we have that $|z_0| = 1$ and so $|f(z_0)| \geq \sqrt{|z_0|} = 1$. In particular, since $0$ is not on the boundary, then we have that $|f(0)|\geq 1$.

Now, if f does have a zero on $\mathbb{D}$, say $z_0$, then $f(z_0) = 0$, so that $|f(z_0)| = 0$. Hence, $z_0 = 0$ by our given inequality. However, I'm not sure how to derive a contradiction from here to show that $|f(0)| \geq 1$. How do I proceed forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ has a zero in $\mathbb D$ then it must be in $0$, every other point would violate the inequality. If this is the case, then $f(z) = zg(z)$ for an entire function $g$.

It follows $|g(z)| \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$ for $|z|\leq 1$ which is impossible.